# Adding multiple data to a list in c#

Tags: c#, list

Hi I'm trying to add some data to my list including string and integer. I want to store student's name , last name and phone number in the same list so I'm using class. here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


 namespace educationsystem
{
   public class student 
        {
            public string name { get;set;}
            public string lastname {get;set;}
            public long phone {get;set;}
        }
           List<student> Students = new List<student>();
           Students.Add(new student {name= "mahta",lastname= "sahabi",phone= "3244"});
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("please choose one of the numbers below : "+"\n");
        Console.WriteLine("1.adding new student"+"\n");
        Console.WriteLine("2.adding new course"+"\n");
        Console.WriteLine("3.adding new grade"+"\n");
        Console.WriteLine("4.showing the best student"+"\n");
        Console.WriteLine("5.getting students average"+"\n");
        Console.WriteLine("6.exit"+"\n");
         string input = Console.ReadLine();


             if (input == "1")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                List<int> grades = new List<int>();

                    Console.WriteLine("please enter the students name");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter the students last name");
                    string lastname = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter the students phone number");
                    long phone = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine(name +" "+ lastname +" " + phone);





            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {

            }
            else if (input == "3")
            {

            }
            else if (input == "4")
            {

            }
            else if (input == "5")
            {

            }


        Console.ReadKey();
}

 }
       }
```

but it is not working. My list name is students but the system wouldn't recognize it. would you help me please?

Comment: which list Students  or grades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your list inside your class
Making variables global is not possible in c#.
global variables can be done in languages like PHP and c++

```
class Program
{
    public List<student> Students = new List<student>();
}
```

If you want to make students global accesible from your class you could make it static

```
public static List<student> Students = new List<student>();
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Comment: how should I print my list in output?

Comment: Students.ForEach((student) => { Console.WriteLine($"name = {student.name}\nlastName {student.lastname}\nphone = {student.phone}"); });

Comment: you're the best